# Null Pointer Exceprion .MainActivity$1.onTick(MainActivity.java:23)

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement this code from [this webpage](http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html).

But for some reason I'm getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
    08-05 08:59:09.512: E/AndroidRuntime(875): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-05 08:59:09.512: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.example.basiccountdown.MainActivity$1.onTick(MainActivity.java:23)
```

The code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
    startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    startB.setOnClickListener(this);

    text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

    text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));

    }
```

More stacktrace

```
08-05 09:21:44.313: D/AndroidRuntime(1258): Shutting down VM
08-05 09:21:44.313: W/dalvikvm(1258): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.basiccountdown/com.example.basiccountdown.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.basiccountdown.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.basiccountdown-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.basiccountdown-2, /system/lib]]
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.basiccountdown.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.basiccountdown-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.basiccountdown-2, /system/lib]]
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
08-05 09:21:44.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1258):     ... 11 more
08-05 09:28:51.782: D/AndroidRuntime(1307): Shutting down VM
08-05 09:28:51.782: W/dalvikvm(1307): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
```

Line 23 is `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Can you post the actual code and show which line is line 23 please.

Comment: This is the `onCreate()` method of the `TimerActivity` - right?

Comment: Is your main class named `TimerActivity` or `MainActivity` ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your timer activity class to MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Add your `MainActivity` to the `AndroidManifest`. This should fix the problem. It is the tutorial, which didn't say anywhere that this activity should be added there. It is for new projects, where this happens automatically. Add this into the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.basiccountdown.MainActivity">
```

Then go to Project -> Properties -> Builders too.

Answer (score 0):

if you copied the code you mention there are 2 things i can suggest:

1) check in your manifest if you have defined your main activity properly

2) check in your /res/layout/activity_timer.xml that you have text view with id "timer"